# Get Row-Number of a MAX(Range) Value?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with several items, their volumes and margins. I have no problem in finding the maximum margin with `=MAX(Range)`. What I need to find is the row number of that value.

Let's say I have these values:

```
   A      B    C
1 Item1   5m³  70%
2 Item2   10m³ 80%
3 Item3   2m³  50%
```

The maximum margin would be 80%. Now i need to know that this value belongs to Item 2 in Row 2.
Is there a way to find that out?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the following formula to do that.

### Formula

```
=MATCH(MAX(E2:E4), E2:E4, 0)
```

If you want to include the header, then you have to use this formula:

```
=MATCH(MAX(E2:E4), E1:E4, 0)
```

### Screenshot

[image]

### Remark

The last criterium in the `MATCH` formula, `0` will trigger the function to find the first entry. Use `1` to show the last entry.

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[Get Row-Number of a MAX(Range) Value?](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdEQ2SUdmMkwzdmliWlg2elhpNktJLUE&usp=sharing)**